# What is the process for loading and running a Sinatra app?

Tags: ruby, sinatra

I've just switched to Sinatra for a project, and my project is just:

```
/lib
/test
config.ru
Gemfile
```

In my config.ru file I have:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'bundler'

Bundler.setup unless File.exists?(File.expand_path('../.bundle/environment', __FILE__))
Bundler.require(:default)

Dir.glob File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/*.rb', &method(:require)

run HandHistoryParser
```

It seems to load, and running rackup starts the server without errors.  But I have a simple test script to test the output, and when the script creates HandHistoryParser like

```
@file_reader = HandHistoryParser::FileReader.new("bulk_hands")
```

I get this error:

```
in `<main>': uninitialized constant Object::HandHistoryParser (NameError)
```

For some reason I'm not able to require the library file, even though it works in irb with both of these requires:

```
require './lib/hand_history_parser' 
require '../../lib/hand_history_parser
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

You error message suggests that this might be a scope problem. As in, the module and class constants are getting defined and so on, but with self set to something other than main/the global scope.

Try changing this:

```
Dir.glob File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/lib/*.rb', &method(:require)
```

To:

```
Dir[__FILE__ + '/../lib/*.rb'] { |file| require file }
```

Comment: do you need a .each between the Dir statement and the block?

Comment: yep, it's missing indeed.

Answer (score 0):

wait... what do you mean by test script
we're using rack/test right

imho
a sinatra app will be much more test-friendly if
your main app class can be started independent of config.ru

such that you can require just 'rack/test' and  'app.rb' in your test files